# See through material for 3ds Max

Tags: 3ds-max

I am trying to recreate a diagram of a Brillouin Zone in `3ds Max` which looks as follows:

[image: FCC Brillouin Zone]

I successfully recreated the polygon shape in `Pro/Engineer` and imported the `.prt` into my setup environment (cameras lighting backdrop etc) and it looks like this:

[image: Set up BZ in 3ds Max]

I'm still very new to materials. I'm having trouble finding a material that shows the faceting under the light clearly (seeing the back of the shape through the transparency would also be great but optional) as well as the sphere I placed at its centre. Using solid glass or liquid materials either results in a cloudy transparency (inner sphere poorly visible) or the faceting being really poorly defined if I increase the transparency (sphere visible).

Could you suggest a material + properties that are see through (with a 1.0 refractive index) and yet show the inside clearly. On the link below I include a MWE file of my setup with the BZ and sphere and materials I have been tinkering with. Much appreciated!

[Download 3ds max file from FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/bz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end I got there through intuitive trial and error and minor knowledge boost. I used the following settings:

[image: Standard material settings]

It turns out that using fancy materials was not the solution and the best way was to work out a specular/glossiness and transparency balance for a standard material.

Result:

[image: 1st BZ of FCC material with symmetry points]